# How to check and get the newest file(.xlsx) in a tempfolder?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

Here is a complicated problem...
When I run Python, I want to determine the newest Excel file in temporary folder (`%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\`) and copy it to the `D` drive on Windows.

I searched for examples but there weren't any...

How can I solve this problem?

This is the code below...

```
import os
import win32com.client as win32
import time
import subprocess
import tempfile

dated_files = [(os.path.getmtime(fn), os.path.basename(fn)) for fn in os.listdir(os.getenv('TEMP')) if fn.lower().endswith('.xlsx')]

dated_files.sort()
dated_files.reverse()

newest = dated_files[0][1]
print(newest)
```

=============================================================

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/1002.py", line 11, in <module>
for fn in os.listdir(os.getenv('TEMP')) if fn.lower().endswith('.xlsx')]
  File "D:/M1002.py", line 11, in <listcomp>

for fn in os.listdir(os.getenv('TEMP')) if fn.lower().endswith('.xlsx')]
  File "C:\Python35\lib\genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'SampleCheck.xlsx'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement this yourself yet? Can you please provide a [mcve] of your latest attempt please?

Comment: @idjaw
Of course I tried it myself for 3 days..
but don't have any idea...

Comment: Please show your code. Ensure you meet the criteria of providing a [mcve]

Comment: @idjaw
please see the code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you missed `os.chdir(os.getenv('TEMP'))` before the list comprehension. Or you should do `os.path.join(os.getenv('TEMP'), fn)` to pass it into `os.path.getmtime`.

In more details:

`getmtime` cannot find the file `fn` in the current working directory. So you have to change the working dir (with `os.chdir`) or to use the full path (constructed by `os.path.join` for example).

Comment: yes, you are right. I got the right excel file.
Thank you for your help :)